# Using docker-compose in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

To create a docker image for a tileserver i want to include the generation of the tilemaps via https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles/blob/master/QUICKSTART.md into the build process.

For that i would need to "RUN docker-compose" during the image build process.

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install apt-utils

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install   ca-certificates curl

ENV DOCKER_VERSION 1.12.3
ENV COMPOSE_VERSION 1.9.0

RUN curl -L https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz > /tmp/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz \
 && tar -zxf /tmp/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz -C /tmp \
 && cp /tmp/docker/docker /usr/local/bin/docker \
 && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker \
 && rm -rf /tmp/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz /tmp/docker \
 && curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
 && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# check installation
RUN docker-compose -v

# install git
RUN apt-get -y install git-core

# install gawk
RUN apt-get -y install gawk

# install make
RUN apt-get -y install make

# Clone Maptiles Repo
RUN git clone https://github.com/digitalegarage/openmaptiles /openmaptiles

RUN cd /openmaptiles \
    && bash quickstart.sh bayern

# Start Maptiels Server
# on port 8080
CMD make start-tileserver
```

Trying to build this dockerfile seems to succefully install docker-compose
but starting docker-compose via the bash script results in the following error

```
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

Answer (score 1):

## `Docker Build Kit`

---

You have to mount volume `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro` to intermediate containers while building images.

For sure, you know how to mount volumes with typical containers. However, the case here is intermediate containers.

#### Can we  do it ?

### Brief answer:

Yes using the experimental feature "build kit".

### Detailed answer:

**step1: Dockerfile**

- At the beginning of the Dockerfile put this line :

  ```
  # syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
  ```
- Mount volumes inside Dockerfile as following:

  ```
  RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/var/run/docker.sock,source=/var/run/docker.sock \
      docker-compose -v
  ```

  In general, Use this mount with any "RUN" that requires communication with the docker engine.

**step2: Build the image:**

- export this variable before running `docker build` :

  ```
  export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
  ```

Now build your new image like a Boss :

```
    docker build ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because docker daemon is not running inside your container. So you need to have a connection with any host that running docker daemon and specified DOCKER_HOST env variable. I suggest you link your container with another docker-in-docker container(https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/). Take a look into one of the existing [docker-in-docker](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind) solutions out there.

Comment: first, thank you for that quick answer. I already used the default docker-in-docker image resulting in the same error. Because its easyer to use the bash script im using debain and install docker with RUN curl -L https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz > /tmp/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz \
 && tar -zxf /tmp/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz -C /tmp \
 && cp /tmp/docker/docker /usr/local/bin/docker \

Comment: i think that there could be a difference beetween starting docker-compose in dockerfile build and running container